Apache Camel Project - NOTIFY/LISTEN sql
Is it possible to read the newly inserted data in the table using trigger function in the Apache Camel project?
I am using Apache Camel and PostgresDB and created the trigger function in the db. Tested the trigger function in db site. It's working fine. But Apache Camel is not listen the notification from the db.
I need to read newly inserted record in the table and process the data and send a mail.
Is it possible to read the newly inserted data in the table using trigger function in the Apache Camel project?

Have you seen this component for Postgress LISTEN
https://camel.apache.org/components/4.4.x/pgevent-component.html

yes. i used  https://camel.apache.org/components/4.4.x/pgevent-component.html this components.But its not listen the notification.
mycode -> code
from("sql:LISTEN my_channel?dataSource=#flinkPostgresDataSource")
.routeId("PostgresListenerRoute")
.process(exchange -> {    String notificationMessage = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
log.info("Received notification: {}", notificationMessage);
});
